# Combining multiple csv files in bash, splitting the lines into different rows

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I've gotten >100 `csv` files, each containing >1000 measurements structured like the following two example files

MR44825_radiomics_MCA.csv

```
Case-1_Image: MR44825_head.nii.gz
Case-1_diagnostics_Configuration_EnabledImageTypes: {'Original': {}, 'LoG': {'sigma': [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]}, 'Wavelet': {}}
Case-1_diagnostics_Image-original_Mean: -917.2822725885565
```

MR47987_radiomics_MCA.csv

```
Case-1_Image: MR47987_head.nii.gz
Case-1_diagnostics_Configuration_EnabledImageTypes: {'Original': {}, 'LoG': {'sigma': [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]}, 'Wavelet': {}}
Case-1_diagnostics_Image-original_Mean: -442.31589128260026
```

The label is always some string of varying length, the distincter to the measurement is always the first `:`. Each measurement contains identical labels. The measurements themselves may contain `,` but then the related values are enclosed by `{}`.

Now I want to merge these files, preferably using `bash`. The output `csv` should be structured like the following:

```
Case-1_Image,Case-1_diagnostics_Configuration_EnabledImageTypes,Case-1_diagnostics_Image-original_Mean
MR44825_head.nii.gz,{'Original': {}, 'LoG': {'sigma': [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]}, 'Wavelet': {}},-917.2822725885565
MR47987_head.nii.gz,{'Original': {}, 'LoG': {'sigma': [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]}, 'Wavelet': {}},-442.31589128260026
```

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: There is no CSV input file in your question. Please [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input (at least 2 CSVs since you're asking for help to merge multiple files) and the expected output given that input.

Comment: As you have commas in one of your datafield (json), this will not work at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- OP has a reason for using a non-JSON format (and OP is 'ok' with having commas (`,`) as both delimiter and data)
- all source files have the same number of lines
- there are no blank lines in any of the source files
- all source files have the same labels preceding the first `:`
- all source files have their labels in the same order
- the number, and spelling, of labels is not known up front (ie, we'll need to dynamically parse, store and print the labels)

One `awk` idea:

**NOTE**: a bit lengthy due to need to dynamically process labels

```
awk '
BEGIN  { split("",hdr)                        # declare hdr as an array
         split("",data)                       # declare data as an array
         ndx=1                                # init array index
       }

function print_row() {                        # function to print a row

pfx=""                                        # first column will have a NULL prefix

if ( length(hdr) > 0  )                       # print the header row?
   { for ( i in hdr )
       { printf "%s%s", pfx, hdr[i]
         pfx=","                              # 2nd-nth columns will have a "," prefix
       }
     printf "\n"
     split("",hdr)                            # clear hdr[] array so we do not print it again
   }

pfx=""                                        # reset prefix for printing data row

if ( length(data) > 0 )                       # print a data row?
   { for ( i in data )
         { printf "%s%s", pfx, data[i]
           pfx=","                            # 2nd-nth columns will have a "," prefix
         }
     printf "\n"
     split("",data)                           # clear the data[] array for the next file
     ndx=1                                    # reset our array index for the next file
   }
}

FNR==1 { print_row() }                        # if this is a new file then print contents of last file

       { if ( FNR==NR )                       # if this is the first file then make sure to populate the hdr[] array
            hdr[ndx]=gensub(/:$/,"","g",$1)   # strip trailing ":" from field #1; store in hdr[] array
         $1=""                                # clear field #1
         data[ndx]=gensub(/^ /,"","g",$0)     # strip leading " " from the line; store in data[] array
         ndx++                                # increment array index
         next
       }

END    { print_row() }                        # flush last set of data[] to stdout

' MR*MCA.csv
```

When run against the 2x sample data files this generates:

```
Case-1_Image,Case-1_diagnostics_Configuration_EnabledImageTypes,Case-1_diagnostics_Image-original_Mean
MR44825_head.nii.gz,{'Original': {}, 'LoG': {'sigma': [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]}, 'Wavelet': {}},-917.2822725885565
MR47987_head.nii.gz,{'Original': {}, 'LoG': {'sigma': [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]}, 'Wavelet': {}},-442.31589128260026
```

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the time and effort you invested here!
Your assumptions are all correct, besides the last one. I do know the number and spelling of all the labels and can provide them if helpful. 

Since I'm a novice in coding in general and in `awk` in particular, I might need a bit of time to implement this before I can give you a feedback. 
Simpling executing the code you provided in the folder of a few test `csv` files produces the following error for me:

Comment: `awk: line 7: illegal reference to variable hdr
awk: line 8: illegal reference to variable hdr
awk: line 12: illegal reference to variable hdr
awk: line 18: illegal reference to variable data
awk: line 19: illegal reference to variable data`

Comment: hmmmm ... what's the output from running `awk --version` on your system? if those are the only error messages, they're all from array references inside the function; I'm wondering if your `awk` version requires the pre-declaration steps at the top of the script ??  I've edited the answer to move the `BEGIN` block to the top so the array pre-declarations now occur prior to the function definition.

Comment: `awk --version` didn't work, resulted in `awk: not an option: --version`.
`awk -W version` gave a result, `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan`. So updating `mawk` might bring the solution?

Comment: Running the edited code including `BEGIN` results in the following error:
`awk: 2: unexpected character 0xc2
awk: 2: unexpected character 0xc2
awk: 3: unexpected character 0xc2
awk: 4: unexpected character 0xc2
awk: 5: unexpected character 0xc2
`

Comment: for me: `awk --version` => `GNU Awk 5.1.0`, so there's likely to be some stuff I'm doing that's not supported in your environment; I've made some changes to see if I can get around the errors you've reported; let me know what (new) errors the updated code generates

Comment: the `0xc2` reference may be an issue with how you've pulled the code into your environment ... perhaps an issue with cut-n-paste or re-typing, eg, make sure you're using single quotes instead of back ticks; one other idea would be to remove the comments from your code before running (wild guess your older version of `awk` is having problems parsing comments ... ???); and, yeah, getting a newer version of `awk` (preferably `gawk` == `GNU awk`) would likely help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226712/discussion-between-adrian-mak-and-markp-fuso).

Comment: Just adding that after installing `gawk` this solution worked. Many thanks to this great community and sorry for my own short comings, I'm hoping to be able to contribute someday as well.

Comment: re: works with `gawk` ... I'm going to rollback a few of the changes I made while trying to get it to work with `mawk`; post back if any of these rollbacks break your code ...

Comment: FWIW the only non-POSIX constructs I see in your code are `length(array)` and `gensub()`. I suspect it's `length(hdr)` that was causing the `awk: line 7: illegal reference to variable hdr` message (and same for `data`).

Comment: The `for (i in ...)`s will shuffle the array indices into "random" order though so that may be a concern as the order in data may not be the same as the order in hdr and neither might be the order desired. To ensure the order is consistent between the 2 (if that's desirable, I haven't really studied the question or this answer) then always loop on the same array indices but it looks like the index is incremental numeric so `for (i=1; i in hdr; i++)` for each array would solve both problems.

Answer (score 0):

CSV doesn't really make sense for the data you presented, and the pseudo-CSV you say you want as output makes little sense and will be hard to process further. Perhaps converting each input file to JSON would make more sense, and allow for processing using standard tools.

```sh
awk -F ': ' 'FNR==1 { name=$2 }
    FNR==2 { j = substr($0, length($1)+3); gsub(/\047/, "\042", j) }
    FNR==3 { sub(/^{/, "{\042name\042: \042" name "\042,", j);
        sub(/}$/, ",\042mean\042: " $2 "}", j);
        print j }' *.csv >output.jsonl
```

The output should be something like

```
{"name":"MR20584_head.nii.gz","Original": {}, "LoG": {"sigma": [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]}, "Wavelet": {},"mean": -917.2822725885565}
{"name":"MR30211_head.nii.gz","Original": {}, "LoG": {"sigma": [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]}, "Wavelet": {},"mean":-1024.287275914652}
```

This format is JSON lines, i.e. each line is valid JSON, but the file itself isn't proper JSON.

Demo: https://ideone.com/ue0Crd

Of course, if you can fix the tool which generated this useless format in the first place, even better.

Comment: Not sure why it's better to use `\042` than `\"`.

Comment: I guess it's not better *per se;* do you think it's worse?

Comment: For me personally it just makes the code slightly harder to read and it takes me a few secs to remind/convince myself that `\042` is `"` and then I spend time trying to figure out what's causing the code to require `\042`s instead of just the character they represent before eventually concluding there's no practical reason for it so for me `\042` is worse than `"` or `\"` as needed but I suppose YMMV. Down that path though - what other characters could we replace with ASCII escape sequences... could make for some very interesting scripts :-).

Comment: Yeah, I could totally appreciate an Obfuscated Aw Context ... To boldly take Awk to the place where `sed` has supremely reigned ever since people stopped writing TECO macros.